# PHP check if file not exists in any directory

Tags: php, file-exists

How to check if a file doesn't exist in any directory, add into the `$notexists` array.

```
foreach($files as $file){
   foreach ($folders as $this_folder) {
     if (file_exists($this_folder.$file)) {
        $exists[] =$file;
        continue;
     }else{
         // What to do if file is not exist in any directory, add into array.
         $notexists[] = '';
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `$this_folder` in `file_exists()`? `$folder_path` seems to be the same in all iterations of the second `foreach()`.

Comment: You need to do the add at the end of the loop. Your `else` runs if it's not in the current directory, even though it might be in another directory.

Comment: @Syscall sorry my mistake, changed!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wait until the end of the loop to know if the file was not found in any of the directories.

And `continue;` should be `break;`. `continue` restarts starts the next iteration of the current loop, but once you find the file you want to exit the loop completely.

```
foreach($files as $file){
    $found = false;
    foreach ($folders as $this_folder) {
        if (file_exists($this_folder.$file)) {
            $exists[] =$file;
            $found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!$found) {
        // What to do if file is not exist in any directory, add into array.
        $notexists[] = $file;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`array_diff()`](https://php.net/array_diff) to check the files that was not found:

```
foreach($files as $file){
   foreach ($folders as $this_folder) {
     if (file_exists($this_folder.$file)) {
        $exists[] =$file;
        break;
     }
}
$notexists = array_diff($files, $exists);
```

Answer (score 0):

you could store them directly after `else` condition since your using `break;` you dont have to worry about iteration

```
foreach($files as $file){
 foreach ($folders as $folder_path) {

   /* NOTE : the '@' here before the file_exists() function 
      is to manage this function errors by yourself after the `else` condition , 
      otherways you can remove it to see the native php errors .
      */

   if (@file_exists($folder_path.$file)) {
   $exists[] = $file;
   break;

   }else{
   $notexists[] = $file;
   }
 }
}
```

**RESULT :**

> Exist Files      : `Array ( [0] => index.php [1] => head.php )` 
>    Non Exist ones  : `Array ( [0] => random_file.random )`

but be aware that you need to define those arrays before you use them inside the conditions so you dont get undefined errors later if they return an empty array when you loop them as a result .
so before your first `foreach()` add those variables definition

```
$exists    = array();
$notexists = array();
$folders   = array('./'); // your folders list ofc should be here ..
```

Comment: since his having `}else{` after that condition he can sort a custom error spsly if he have a professional script and he want to manage all the errors by himself . but even that you point is good , i should remind him with a note about that , thank you :)